# Formatting float with zero padded and implied decimal

Tags: python, string-formatting

is there a mini language way for format like this?

cram a float into 9999^99  zero padded ^ is a implied decimal.

I was doing this

```
for x in (450.5, 50.0, 50.0043, 9999.989,0.5):
    print ('{0:06}'.format(round(x,2)).replace('.','')+'000')[0:6]
```

but felt a little dirty afterwords...   so I changed it...

I know I could rip apart the float and put it back together

```
for x in (450.5, 50.0, 50.0043, 9999.989,0.5, 4):
    print '{0:04}{1:0<2}'.format(int(x),int(x % 1 * 100))
```

this did not make me feel much better.
I know what I am doing but only because I wrote it...

anyone have a great way that is concise and clear?  Or is this code clear enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  print "{:06.0f}".format(round(100*x))
```

Comment: @mgilson for that to work you need an ```int()``` around the argument of ```format()```, otherwise you get a ```ValueError```

Comment: @wnnmaw -- Looks like you're correct.  I just assumed it would work since `'%d' % 3.14` works Ok.